# Angular 2, combine spread and barrel for imports

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to clean up my code and minimize all the import code that I have to setup everywhere.

So in **`index.ts`** in my services folder I set up a barell:

```
import { Service1} from "./service1.service";
import { Service2 } from "./service2.service";
import { Service3 } from "./service3.service";

export const commonServices = [
    Service1,
    Service2,
    Service3,
];
```

So that I can minimize the import code in **`app.module.ts`** using the spread operator.

```
...

import { commonServices } from "./common/services";

@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [
        ...commonServices,
    ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

But in **`some.component.ts`**, I can't use a single import since `index.ts` doesn't barrel the specific services as well.

```
...

// This doesn't work
// import { Service1, Service2 } from "../../core/services";

// I have to do this
import { Service1 } from "../../core/services/service1.service";
import { Service2 } from "../../core/services/service2.service";

@Component({
})
export class SomeComponent {
}
```

How can I setup `index.ts` to also export the names of the services, is there a nice clean way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
// index.ts
export { Service1} from "./service1.service";
export { Service2 } from "./service2.service";
export { Service3 } from "./service3.service";

// app.module.ts
import * as commonServices from "./common/services";
  ...
  providers: [
    Object.keys(commonServices).map(svc => commonServices[svc]),
  ]

// some.component.ts
import { Service1, Service2 } from "../../core/services";
```

Note, you don't need to spread **commonServices**, Angular does that automatically, in fact it could be any nested array, e.g. `[Service1, [Service2], [[[Service3]]]]`, Angular will flatten all that.

Comment: But how do I combine this with the `commonServices` export? This means I have to both import and export all services in `index.ts` right?

Comment: Don't export commonServices at all, just import whole `index.ts` **as** commonServices (it will be in one place only anyway, you could even import them manually).

Comment: Oh, wait I get it.. when you `import * as commonServices`, you will get an object commonServices.Service1, commonServices.Service2... You can transform that into array, then use in `providers[]`

Comment: Hm ok. Thank you. I will play around with it, but at some point it starts to get more complex than just using the original imports :)

Comment: Updated the answer... It is just a bit complex, but you only do it once, and keep clean barrels for imports in other places.